# Stuck with calculating exponents in Java (Taylor Series)

Tags: java, taylor-series, exponent

I'm a bit stumped. I'm working on a homework question that requires you to find e^x through a series of 30 iterations: `1 + x + x^2/2! ... x^n/n!`. In this case `n = 30` and the range for `x` is -3 through 3. Seems straightforward enough. However when trying to execute it in Java I'm finding that I'm baffled.

The thought was to run two for loops. The outer loop for the iterations of `x` and the inner loop for the iterations for `n`. Here is the code so far:

```
double series = 1.0;

for (int x=-3; x<=3; x++)
{
    for (int n=1; n<=x+30; n++)
        {
            series = series + (x^n)/n;
            n*=n;
        } 
    System.out.println(""+ x +"\t   "+ (series+1));
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ^ is XOR in Java. Use Math.pow()

Comment: run a google search for "java x to the power of y", read the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to pay more attention to every single variable and the value changes inside the loops to better verify your code.

You have done a few mistakes:

- multiplied n to itself and then divided by n as well. According to your formula you need to power the number by n, not nFactorial. Moreover nFactorial is a large number to be stored (and get accurate results), better use the advantage of dividing by n and multiplying by x at every step (see below code).
- You have also used the XOR operator. Instead use the Math.pow() method.
- You need to initialize the series value in each inner loop start.
- If you started with initial value of 1, do not need to print (series+1) at end. Better initialize it to 0, or remove +1 in the print.

The following code would solve your purpose better.

```
    double series = 1.0;
    double term = 1.0;

    for (int x = -3; x <= 3; x++) {
        series = 1.0;
        term = 1.0;
        for (int n = 1; n <= 30; n++) {
            term = (term * x / n);
            series += term;
        }
        System.out.println("" + x + "\t   " + (series));

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is my very first Java program and I do very much appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @James You are welcome. Hope the feedback helped .If this answers your question, you can accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your formula with MATH.POW like this:

```
    for (int x=-3; x<=3; x++)
    {
        for (int n=1; n<=x+30; n++)
            {
                series = series + (Math.pow(x,n)/n);
                n*=n;
            } 
        System.out.println(""+ x +"\t   "+ (series+1));
    }
```